# How to use jquery to close modal window, by emulating the modal's close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

My website has a modal window that pops up when a user clicks a link. The modal is made purely with CSS3, but I'm trying to implement a function so that when a user presses the escape key, it will close the modal window.

I've successfully been able to do this using jquery, except that if I press escape and it closes the modal, I am then **unable** to re-open the modal unless I refresh the page. The modal window has a "Close" link inside of it that does not produce this problem.

How do I close the modal window using the escape key so that it produces the same effect as if I clicked "close" within the modal?

**Here is the code for the modal:**

//Opens the modal

```
<label for="lightbox-demo">Launch Lightbox</label>
```

//Modal code

```
<aside class="lightbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="state" id="lightbox-demo" />
  <article class="content">

    <main class="main">
  <form method="post" action="submit.php" id="contactform" class="signin">
 <h1>Drop us a line</h1> 
  <h2>We'll reply within 24 hours</h2> 
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />
<input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)" required title="Whoops! Invalid email"/>
       <div class="antispam">
       <br /><input name="url" type="hidden" /></div>
       <textarea name="message" id="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Write away!" required minlength="15" required title="Must be at least 15 characters"></textarea>
        <button id="flybutton">
            <p>Ready, Aim... </p>
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
                <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M462,54.955L355.371,437.187l-135.92-128.842L353.388,167l-179.53,124.074L50,260.973L462,54.955z
M202.992,332.528v124.517l58.738-67.927L202.992,332.528z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
</form>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
      <button class="button" type="button">Do something</button>
      <label class="button" for="lightbox-demo">Close</label>
    </footer>
  </article>
  <label class="backdrop" for="lightbox-demo"></label>
</aside>
```

and here's the faulty jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(".lightbox").hide();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(".lightbox").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

How do I change this JS to act like the close button?

Thank you

Comment: which is the plugin used?

Comment: I think you're asking where I got this code?  I found it here: http://www.cssscript.com/stylish-responsive-lightbox-with-pure-css-css3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the click event manually, by selecting the close button element

```
$('#lightbox-demo + .content footer label[for="lightbox-demo"]').click()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9ezw7kar/)

---

It is much easier if you can give an ID to the close button

```
<label id="lightbox-demo-close" class="button" for="lightbox-demo">Close</label>
```

then

```
$('#lightbox-demo-close').click()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9ezw7kar/2/)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but your solution won't close the popup window with escape key, which is what I'm after. How do I adapt your answer to also close the pop-up form if user presses 'esc'. Thank you